# Move object in circular motion

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I often use the following code to move an object in a circular motion.

```
vector.x = vector.x * Math.cos(.25) - vector.z * Math.sin(.25);
vector.z = vector.z * Math.cos(.25) + vector.x * Math.sin(.25);
```

This moves the object perpendicular to the bottom of my scene. How can I get my object to move in a circular motion through the y plane. I'm not sure how to correctly phrase that.

Comment: Using .x and .z you are rotating around the y-axis. If you want to rotate around the x-axis, use .y and .z

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. What if I need it to move through all three planes

Comment: It would depend on how you want to move it but a linear combination of the above would do.

Comment: so I just tried that. But I cant seems to get the object to move up and down

Comment: You have to post code or create a simple fiddle.